# Get the longest and shortest "chains" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Consider this schema:

```
create table Operation(id integer, name varchar(100));
create table Pipeline(operation_in integer, operation_out integer);
```

`Pipeline` has foreign keys to `Operations`, so pipelines are chained, in a way. `operation_out` is nullable. How do I get the names of operations in both the longest and the shortest pipeline chains using MySQL?

Operations look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Operation VALUES (1, 'operation one');
```

While the pipelines look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO Pipeline VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO Pipeline VALUES (2, 4);
INSERT INTO Pipeline VALUES (4, 7);
INSERT INTO Pipeline VALUES (7, NULL);
```

I.e. the chain here would be operations with ID 1, 2, 4, 7 and expected result along the lines of:

```
"operation one", "operation two", "operation four"...
```

After a few hours of research, I am not sure quite what the solution I am looking for.

Any MySQL version is applicable.

Comment: I don't see how there are chains (longer than two). Each pipeline consists of a maximum of two operations, doesn't it?

Comment: Please provide a few records of sample data for both tables, along with the expected results (as tabular text or create/insert statements), to clarify your requirement.

Comment: [some ideas](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=1763&m=0)

Comment: Are there any cycles, or none at all?

Comment: @GMB will do shortly.

Comment: @TheImpaler no, cycles are guaranteed not to exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.x you can use a Recursive CTE to find the chains you need.

For example:

```
with recursive
a as (
  select
    p.operation_in,
    p.operation_out as current_out,
    o.name as op_names,
    concat('', p.operation_in) as chain,
    1 as size
  from pipeline p
  join operation o on o.id = p.operation_in
  where not exists (
    select 1 from pipeline p2 where p2.operation_out = p.operation_in
  )
  union all
  select
    a.operation_in,
    p.operation_out,
    concat(op_names, ', ', o.name),
    concat(chain, ',', p.operation_in),
    size + 1
  from a
  join pipeline p on p.operation_in = a.current_out
  join operation o on o.id = p.operation_in
),
chains as (
  select * from a where current_out is null
)
select op_names, chain, size
from chains
where size = (select max(size) from chains)  -- finds the longest one
   or size = (select min(size) from chains); -- finds the shortest one
```

Result:

```
op_names                           chain    size
---------------------------------  -------  ----
op-nine, op-six                    9,6         2
op-one, op-two, op-four, op-seven  1,2,4,7     4
```

The data script I used is:

```
create table operation (id integer, name varchar(100));
create table pipeline (operation_in integer, operation_out integer);

insert into operation values (1, 'op-one');
insert into operation values (2, 'op-two');
insert into operation values (4, 'op-four');
insert into operation values (6, 'op-six');
insert into operation values (7, 'op-seven');
insert into operation values (9, 'op-nine');

insert into pipeline values (1, 2);
insert into pipeline values (2, 4);
insert into pipeline values (4, 7);
insert into pipeline values (7, null);
insert into pipeline values (9, 6);
insert into pipeline values (6, null);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a ton.